# How are multiple case statements used in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this may be an easy question, but I've been stumped on this for the past hour and am not sure what terms to lookup that accurately describe what I am trying to do.

I am using application with Oracle 12C DB and i want to use multiple cases in this statement for the same field eg. `INVC_TYPE= 0,2`. First case: if its `2` then `QTY*-1`, and case no 2: if its `0` then `regular` and if its `0` then `return`.

So please there is anyone can help me:

```
select
t.ITEM_SID,
i.SBS_NO as INVC_SBS,
i.STORE_NO as INVCSTORENO,
s.STORE_NO as STORENO,
s.STORE_CODE as STORECODE,
s.STORE_NAME,
i.INVC_NO,
i.CREATED_DATE,
i.INVC_SID,
i.INVC_TYPE,
i.CASHIER_ID,
to_char(i.CREATED_DATE) as INVCDATE,
t.ORIG_PRICE as INVCORIGPRICE,
t.PRICE as INVCPRICE,
t.COST as INVCCOST,
case
when i.INVC_TYPE=2 then t.QTY*-1 
else t.QTY 
end as INVCQTY 
case when i.INVC_TYPE=0 then i.INVC_TYPE="REGULAR"
case when i.INVC_TYPE=2 then i.INVC_TYPE="RETURN"
else 'NA' 
end as INVCTYPE
from invoice i, invc_item t, SBS_STORE_LIST s
where 
INVC_TYPE in (0,2) and
i.invc_sid = t.invc_sid and
i.STORE_NO = s.STORE_NO and 
i.REF_INVC_SID is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t.ITEM_SID,
    i.SBS_NO as INVC_SBS,
    i.STORE_NO as INVCSTORENO,
    s.STORE_NO as STORENO,
    s.STORE_CODE as STORECODE,
    s.STORE_NAME,
    i.INVC_NO,
    i.CREATED_DATE,
    i.INVC_SID,
    i.INVC_TYPE,
    i.CASHIER_ID,
    to_char(i.CREATED_DATE) as INVCDATE,
    t.ORIG_PRICE as INVCORIGPRICE,
    t.PRICE as INVCPRICE,
    t.COST as INVCCOST,
    case 
        when i.INVC_TYPE = 2 then t.QTY * - 1
        else t.QTY
        end as INVCQTY,
    case 
        when i.INVC_TYPE = 0 then i.INVC_TYPE = 'REGULAR'
        when i.INVC_TYPE = 2 then i.INVC_TYPE = 'RETURN'
        else 'NA'
        end as INVCTYPE
from invoice i
join invc_item t on i.invc_sid = t.invc_sid
join SBS_STORE_LIST s on i.STORE_NO = s.STORE_NO
where INVC_TYPE in (0, 2)
    and i.REF_INVC_SID is null;
```

Also, notice the explicit join syntax in place of comma based join. Always use this syntax as this is modern and clearer.

Comment: sorry to say its showing same error missing keyword ?

Comment: @AbdulazizHasanAldabbagh - Updated

Answer (score 1):

These are the issues with your code, to begin with.

1. You are missing comma between 2 case statements.
2. you are using `case` keyword twice in same column.
3. In `THEN` part of case, you are assigning a value. You should just return a value
4. Not an error but you should use proper join syntax

   ```
      select t.ITEM_SID,
       i.SBS_NO as INVC_SBS,
       i.STORE_NO as INVCSTORENO,
       s.STORE_NO as STORENO,
       s.STORE_CODE as STORECODE,
       s.STORE_NAME,
       i.INVC_NO,
       i.CREATED_DATE,
       i.INVC_SID,
       i.INVC_TYPE,
       i.CASHIER_ID,
       to_char(i.CREATED_DATE) as INVCDATE,
       t.ORIG_PRICE as INVCORIGPRICE,
       t.PRICE as INVCPRICE,
       t.COST as INVCCOST,
       case 
           when i.INVC_TYPE = 2 
               then t.QTY * - 1
           else t.QTY
           end as INVCQTY,
       case i.INVC_TYPE
           when  0 then 'REGULAR'
           when  2 then 'RETURN'
           else 'NA'
           end as INVCTYPE
   from invoice i
   join invc_item t 
      on i.invc_sid = t.invc_sid
   join SBS_STORE_LIST s 
      on i.STORE_NO = s.STORE_NO
   where INVC_TYPE in (0, 2)
       and i.REF_INVC_SID is null;
   ```